# Html Helper in Asp.net MVC and Awesome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-awesome

I have Added `ASP.net MVC Awesome` dll as refference and put `themes` , `js` and `css` file to my project and add awesome namespaces in`\Views\web.config` . Project Build Succesfully but html helper doesn`t work in intellisense.

Comment: could you please give more details, 
the base html helper doesn't work, things like Html.Textbox or Html.Awe().Textbox, if you still write it and run does the page work, do you get an error message ?

Answer (score 0):

try follow the instructions on the [installation page](http://aspnetawesome.com/learn/mvc/Installation) and it should just work

or if you just do the first step and download the [minimum setup demo](http://aspnetawesome.com/Download/MvcMinSetupDemo), open the solution file and Build, this is when all the packages get pulled from nuget ( note you have to have packages restore enabled, see readme.txt in the demo download), then you will have a running demo project that you can copy from file by file until you get it working in your other project.

also next to Omu.AwesomeMvc.dll there's is Omu.AwesomeMvc.xml, the presence of that file will insure that you have documentation for intellisense

Comment: what is the live nuget code for that **ASP.net MVC Awesome** tool? Install-Package MvcProjectAwesome is not working. When I run that, I got These errors. 


    Install-Package : Unable to find package 'MvcProjectAwesome'
At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package MvcProjectAwesome
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :          NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackag eCommand

Comment: @Alp that package was removed, the nuget packages mentioned in the answer are the microsoft asp.net mvc package and related